# Plotsbands along x-axis causes issues in stacked column charts - Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Take a look at this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/XZtkM/

If you click on the legend to hide the series, its not hidden properly.  However if the plotBands option is removed from x-Axis, the hiding works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/XZtkM/1/

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Thanks that helped. I have one more question related to this. Is it possible to obtain the color of a plotBand using the xAxis or yAxis object? xAxis.plotBands always returns undefined.http://jsfiddle.net/D5hek/

Answer (score 0):

It is related with incorrect plogBands definition. In case when you configure it proeprly (http://jsfiddle.net/XZtkM/2/) legend click will work correct, as well.

```
plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
            color: '#FCFFC5',
            from: 1372224600,
            to:1372224600
        }],
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands